# Ask user to save changes before leaving a web page - Angular JS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating an ASP.net MVC application with C#.

In the main .cshtml page, I am showing a list of user names on the left hand side of the page.

When the user clicks on any Username from the left, it display the "Personal Details" form for that User in a "partial view" on the Right Hand Side of the page.

**Current Functionality**

1. There is a "Save" button on the "Personal Details" Partial view form.
2. User can make changes in the Personal Details and hit Save to save the changes made in the partial view.

**Desired Functionality**

1. User makes changes in the Personal Details of any record.
2. Now, the user forgot to hit Save and clicked on the Other Username from the left hand side.
3. It should "AUTOMATICALLY SAVE" the changes made in the partial view.

Is it possible to execute the Save button trigger event of the partial view from main view ?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to save the form automatically you can call angular  Submit on **Other Username click** , This snippet  shows example of how.

The `onUserNameClick()` method invokes same angular submit.

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.list = [];
  $scope.text = 'hello';
  $scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.text) {
      $scope.list.push($scope.text);
      $scope.text = '';
    }
  };


}

function onUserNameClick() {
  angular.element('#submit').trigger('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>



<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form ng-submit="submit()">Enter form input values to test
      <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Regular Form Submit" />
      <pre>Form values={{list}}</pre>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<button onClick="onUserNameClick()">Other username click</button>
```

Comment: thanks Karthik. The form is in the partial view. Would this work with that architecture too ?